# haproxy cannot load errorfile files

Tags: haproxy

I've been at this on and off for months trying to get this haproxy to load custom errorfile object

O/S OpenSUSE LEAP 15.1
HAProxy: 2.0.14

Config:
defaults
...stuf....
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/test.http

test.http: I've tried files from the net, created simple  entries, absolutely nothing will take.
I've given haproxy ownershipe of the files set various permissions, ensired "CRLF" on the files, nothing

I'm at wits end.

here's a sample:

HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Connection Error
    
    
        
            
            
                Some message here

Comment: You know that it only works for errors generated by HAProxy itself, don't you?  If the 403 comes from a backend, it's a no go.

Comment: what's your condition for 403? I would try to use the following `http-response set-status 403 if %[status] 403` the doc for that http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4.2-http-response%20set-status